# Verify integrity of /lib /lib64

Tags: linux, lib, corrupt, debian-buster

in Debian Buster is their a way to check integrity of /lib and /lib64 and if corrupted to restore them?
Iam looking for a while now, but Iam not so familiar with Linux and could not find anything. If possible I would avoid the time to reinstall linux again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use :

```
dpkg --verify
```

It will check that all files belonging to a package have the same hash as recorded from the package's metadata.

Corrupted files appear with a `5` as the third character :

```
??5??????   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_radeon.so.1.0.1
```

This useful to detect accidental corruption, but not malicious modifications (e.g. rootkit)

Comment: If it shows nothing then its all good, isn't it?

Comment: yes, in my case it showed a few configuration files, so I modified a file in /usr/lib to be sure

Comment: Ok, thanks then my problem is located elsewhere, I was worried because in my /lib64 are only 3 files.